# How does the Google Vision Client get its methods?

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-sdk

I have been clicking around for a while.

The Google Vision Python SDK has a main class: `ImageAnnotatorClient`: see [here](https://github.com/googleapis/python-vision/blob/fc30dda4bb80f3c7672c67943595249daa02fa47/google/cloud/vision_v1/services/image_annotator/client.py#L78)

This class, at runtime, has methods with the same name as [these](https://github.com/googleapis/python-vision/blob/6679dc1c7e845d18e79baaccc585b432c343feb9/google/cloud/vision_v1/types/image_annotator.py#L107-L119)

I have been trying to figure out how are these methods added to the class to no avail. Can someone point me to it?

Answer (score 0):

It is being added [here](https://github.com/googleapis/python-vision/blob/c313204ee6c251c9e72c9fdaa13c5c35e91f721e/google/cloud/vision_v1/__init__.py#L111)

Following the code from thereon makes it obvious.